# Hide column from Typo3 backend

Tags: php, typo3

greetings..
Is there any way to complete hide column from backend?
i researched a lot and find some solution 
i.e.

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.colPos.removeItems = 3
```

or

```
mod.SHARED.colPos_list = 1,0,2
```

above code prevent user to add/edit action on "border" column.
but i want to remove completely from backend.
**creating new backend layout is one solution.**
is there any way to achieve this without creating new backend layout.
need a quick help.
Thanks in Advance.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is no other solution than creating a new backend layout.